# getjson jquery parsing an array

Tags: jquery, ajax, json, arrays, getjson

Got the simplified array working see below

Following up on the complicated array to parse see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2734989/parsing-a-complicated-array-with-getjson-jquery).

---

**TLDR**: Want to get each heading from an array and insert it into a div without knowing what is inside the div using Jquery - getJSON.

**Edit**: The data is coming from a piece of software that is outputting the JSON string every couple of seconds with new data, so I need to pull the array of data within "d" as in the example below. So i should get "Title" & "034324324"etc for each.

**Edit2** Updated code to match mine exactly..

I have JSON array lets say:

```
{
  "Days": ["Sunday", "Monday", "Tuesday", "Wednesday", "Thursday", "Friday", "Saturday"]
}
```

And I want to parse it as for each "title" to insert it into a div.

Trying along the lines of

```
function getdata() {
31 $.ajaxSetup ({ cache: false}); //<!-- Stops IE from caching data //-->
32 
33 $.getJSON(testurl, function(data) {
34 $.each(data.days, function(i,item){
35 $('#testfield').append('<p>' + item + '</p>');
36
37 });
38 });
```

to no avail.

I am using Getjson in other places but in cases where I know what request I am making.
e.g:

```
$('#name').html(data.Projectname);
```

Which is all working perfectly fine but in this case I need to get the details out of the array without knowing what is inside the array I'm sure there is something simple that I'm missing here or doing wrong ^^.

The JSON I have currently been working with looks like :

```
{"Projectname":"ertyofhj","Projectid":"aqwertyuqw","Projecttitle":"ertyofhj"}
```

The array was just a way to look out pulling out the data without knowing what was inside the array.

I just keep adding more.
Debugging firebug or IE's debugger(Aargh) it will hit

```
33 $.getJSON(testurl, function(data) {
```

then

```
38 });
```

completely skipping

```
34 $.each(data.days, function(i,item){
```

-The GET request fires fine and returns the correct JSON string. But now it will not fill the $.each, or even if I specifically ask for a certain string.
<s>On note of above Firebug is also telling me that it isn't formatted as JSON?</s>

**Changed the original JSON string to something simpler.**(Days of the week) as is days of the week will load. So I am getting somewhere. But I need to be able to call a more complex array. For example (using the days) each day has a specific time on it that I need to display as well also each day should be on a new line tried adding in a " + '< br />' but that doesn't work either. Displayed in an array such as:

```
{
  "Days": ["Sunday": "10.00", "Monday": "12.00", "Tuesday": "09.00", "Wednesday": "10.00", "Thursday": "02.00", "Friday": "05.00", "Saturday": "08.00"]
}
```

And I need to pull Dayname & time for all.

Comment: Or even which sounds harder how to get all the details from a JSON string without an array / knowing what is inside it at all (If it's even possible :P)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$.getJSON(url,
    function(data){
      $.each(data.items, function(i,item){
      $('#testfield').html('<p>' + item.d.title + '</p>');
      });
    });
```

In this code you're going to end up replacing the HTML of the item with ID of 'testfield' with the value over and over ... you might want to try using [jQuery.append](http://api.jquery.com/append/) to add all entries as you've specified above

```
$.getJSON(url,
    function(data){
      $.each(data.items, function(i,item){
      $('#testfield').append('<p>' + item.d.title + '</p>');
      });
    });
```

Comment: That would make perfect sense. But sadly it still wont work for me :P

Comment: Its your data that is formatted wrong.  In your above example of the dates (Weekdays followed by a value) you are incorrectly specifying elements in there.  You would need for example { "Sunday" : "10.00" } etc for each element. See additional answer below.

Answer (score 1):

There is an error in your JSON data: you're not using colons after "d" in the last three items. Is this an example of real data that your application is using, or example data to demonstrate your problem?

Comment: It is the local variable used in the loop.

Comment: It was an example to demonstrate my problem following a working one I had setup with Flickr. from an example. just cut down alot more then the flickr json string. But yes on that note they should have colons.

Comment: Added the colons in as they are in the "test example" I'm trying to use.

Answer (score 1):

Hopefully this example will point you in the right direction

---

```
<html>
<head>
  <title>Stackoverflow</title>
  // ** POINT THIS TO A VALID jquery.js LOCATION
  <script src="jquery.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
  <script>
    var days = [ "Sunday", "Monday", "Tuesday", "Wednesday", "Thursday", "Friday", "Saturday" ];
    // *****************************************************
    // This is your data from getJSON if correctly formatted
    var data = '{"Days":[ {"Sunday":"10.00"}, {"Monday":"12.00"}, {"Tuesday":"09.00"}, {"Wednesday":"10.00"}, {"Thursday":"02.00"}, {"Friday":"05.00"}, {"Saturday":"08.00"}]}';
    runUpdate = function() {
      // *******************************************************
      // Clear the div of all data by replacing it
      $('#testfield').replaceWith('<div id="testfield"></div>');
      var dataObject= $.parseJSON( data );
      $.each( dataObject.Days, function (index, value) {
        // ********************************************
        // Append new elements to the newly created div
        $('#testfield').append("<p>"+days[index]+": "+value[ days[index] ]+"</p>");
      });
    };

    runReset = function() {
      $('#testfield').replaceWith('<div id="testfield">This is original text.</div>');
    };
  </script>
</head>
<body>
  <div id="testfield">
    This is original text.
  </div>
  <div>
    <input type="button" value="Run Update" onclick="runUpdate();" />
    <input type="button" value="Reset" onclick="runReset();" />
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```