# Parsing a complicated array with GetJSON Jquery

Tags: jquery, ajax, json, arrays, getjson

**TLDR:**

1. Started with [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2727546/getjson-jquery-parsing-an-array) simplified it after got some of it working and continuing it here.
2. I need to 'GET' the JSON array
3. Format it correctly and for each within the array place it in the corresponding DIV.
4. ??
5. It works.

---

This is a followup from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2727546/getjson-jquery-parsing-an-array) to simplify and continue.

I need to some complicated JSON data from an array. With it I need the title and it's value. The reason why I am doing this is because I will know what the array is called but not the data that is being generated inside it.

Lets say this new array looks as follows:

```
{
  "Days": [{
      "day": "Sunday",
      "time": "10.00"
    },
    {
      "day": "Monday",
      "time": "12.00"
    },
    {
      "day": "Tuesday",
      "time": "09.00"
    },
    {
      "day": "Wednesday",
      "time": "10.00"
    },
    {
      "day": "Thursday",
      "time": "02.00"
    },
    {
      "day": "Friday",
      "time": "05.00"
    },
    {
      "day": "Saturday",
      "time": "08.00"
    }
  ]
}
```

Fixed thanks to (Matthew Flaschen)

I would need it to get Sunday & 10.00 as well as the same for all of the others.

My code to parse this at the moment is as follows:

```
$.getJSON(url,
  function(data) {
    $.each(data, function(i, item) {
      $('.testfield').append('<p>' + item + '</p>');
    });
  });
```

Without the added times on each date it will parse the data as follows:

```
Sunday, Monday, Tuesday, Wednesday, Thursday, Friday, Saturday
```

With the times added to the days in the array Firebug no longer recognizes it as a JSON string. So I am guessing I have formatted something wrong here. Also, I need each day & time to be on a new line I thought that

```
$('.testfield').append('<p>' + item + '</p>' + '<br />');
```

Would have applied each one to a new line but that did not work.

1. How do I get each day or item to be on a new line?
2. How do I get the $getjson to parse the data correctly day and its value, into a div?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this (reformatted JSON - next time check your JSON with [JSONLint](http://www.jsonlint.com/)):

```
{
    "Days": [
        {
            "Sunday": "10.00",
            "Monday": "12.00",
            "Tuesday": "09.00",
            "Wednesday": "10.00",
            "Thursday": "02.00",
            "Friday": "05.00",
            "Saturday": "08.00" 
        }
    ]
}
```

Script to work with it:

```
 $.getJSON( url, function(data){
  $.each(data.Days[0], function(key,value){
   $('.testfield').append('<p>' + key + ' : ' + value + '</p>');
  });
 });
```

Comment: Haha JSONLint is definitely saved down now :)

Comment: Working perfectly. Thankyou very muchly

Comment: Now I the fun of making sure my JSON coming from server side is formatted correctly ^^

Comment: I think what you were missing, beside the JSON, is the `data.Days[0]` and the `function(key, value)`, see the jQuery.each() document page (http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.each/) :P

Answer (score 1):

That's not valid JSON.  Do something like:

```
{"Days":
[{"day": "Sunday", "time": "10.00"},
 {"day": "Monday", "time": "12.00"},
 {"day": "Tuesday", "time": "09.00"},
 {"day": "Wednesday", "time": "10.00"},
 {"day": "Thursday", "time": "02.00"},
 {"day": "Friday", "time": "05.00"},
 {"day": "Saturday", "time": "08.00"}
]}
```

Always use [JSONLint](http://www.jsonlint.com/) or another validator to check your syntax.

Comment: Formatting it as above i get [Object Object]. Because I am asking for all within "Days"

Comment: Yes, JSON is a subset of JavaScript literal syntax. So that is also a valid object literal.

Comment: Been working on this for a while now making my head a bit dizzy :P Thanks alot for the help.

Answer (score 0):

A little off-topic, but if you don't the contents for sure, you should use a safe method to insert data to DOM. Otherwise your code has a XSS vulnerability.

And besides being a security issue, any data such as "Foo Bar <foo.bar@example.com>" will not render as you (probably) wanted.

For example, you can use the jQuery text() method:

```
$('.testfield').append($('<p></p>').text(item));
```